# Adding a UIView above a UITableView with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a UITableView in a UIViewController that takes up the whole screen.  It's constraints are just horizontal and vertical spaces that have constants of 0 to the superview.  (I basically just dropped the tableView in the center of the ViewController) and had Xcode add missing constraints.

What I want to do is have an animation slide down the UITableView, and then add an activityIndicator above the tableView, spin, and then when my task is done, animate the tableView back.

This is what I have so far:

```
- (void)revealUnderTableView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    NSLog(@"show");

    self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self.activityIndicator setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    [self.view addSubview:_activityIndicator];
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraintW = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_activityIndicator attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1 constant:200];
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraintH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_activityIndicator attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1 constant:200];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:constraintW, constraintH, nil]];
    //    [_activityIndicator setConstrainedView:_activityIndicator width:100 height:100];
    [_activityIndicator setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = 44.;    // 1
    [self.tableView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];  // 2
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded]; // 3
    }];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.activityIndicator.frame));
}
```

My activityIndicator is nowhere to be seen.  I was wondering what I am supposed to do for something like this with Auto Layout.  Do I need to first add a constraint that creates space between the viewController's view and the tableView, and then add the activityIndicator?  Or do I create a new constraint that looks something like

```
"@V:|-[activityIndicator]-[tableView]|"
```

I tried something like this earlier, and I also got no results.  Does someone know how to approach this problem with Auto Layout?  I've only done stuff like this with strings and struts.  Thanks!

Comment: If can simply use `tableHeaderView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. One way is to add a UIView above your table view, and give it constraints to the top and sides of the superview, a 0 length spacing constraint to the top of the table view, and a height constraint. Make IBOutlets to this view, and to its height constraint (I call them aiView and heightCon in my example). In IB edit the height constraint to make its height be 0, which will make that view disappear, and the table view take up the whole screen. In code, when you create the activity indicator, add it to this view and give it centerX and centerY constraints. To make it appear and disappear, you only need to change that height constraint. In my example, I'm toggling that height with successive double taps of a gesture recognizer -- you'd need to change that that to fit your needs.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *aiView;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightCon;

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [self.activityIndicator setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.aiView addSubview:_activityIndicator];

    NSLayoutConstraint *aiCenterX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.activityIndicator attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:0 toItem:self.aiView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *aiCenterY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.activityIndicator attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:0 toItem:self.aiView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0];
    [self.aiView addConstraints:@[aiCenterX, aiCenterY]];
}

- (IBAction)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (! self.activityIndicator.isAnimating) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.6 animations:^{
            self.heightCon.constant = 100;
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
            [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
        }];
    }else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.6 animations:^{
            self.heightCon.constant = 0;
            [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did notice that you initially allocated the activity indicator with CGRectZero which means 0 width and 0 height and then proceeded to define a constraint placing the a constant width and height of 200. I believe what you need to do is to set a breakpoint at this line ->  [_activityIndicator setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

and determine which problem you are having.

1. Is it related to the frame, position or size of your AI  (size = 0, or the AI frame is out of bounds).
2. Maybe you just need a refresh of the view  through
   [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

I use auto layout in the NIB - at that point I will not know if I am dealing with an iPhone4 or iPhone 5 but within the code the information is already available and in this case it will be a lot easier and more efficient to just compute the frame manually as below:

```
 float ai_y = self.view.frame.size.height;
 float ai_x = self.view.frame.size.width;
 CGRect AIrect = CGRectmake (((ai_x / 2) - 100), ((ai_y / 2) - 100), 200,200);
 self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:AIRect];
 [_activityIndicator setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
 [self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
[UIView animateWithDuration:.6 animations:^{
    self.aiHeight.constant = 100;
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    }];
```

I assume you know that you have to remove the AI from the (view) superview when you stop animation by button or gesture:

```
   - (IBAction)Stop_ai:(id)Sender {   
      [self.activityIndicator stop];
      [[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];  // assumes AI is last subview added
      self.activityIndicator = nil;
      return;   }
```